# How do I reinitialize a corrupted USB key on Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

I accidentally borked my USB key using `diskpart.exe` so that neither diskpart nor Partition Manager recognized the device.

When I plugged the key into my Mac, however, the Mac immediately said that it could not recognize the device and showed a super-easy button to "Initialize" the drive—which opened Disk Utility where I could reformat the drive.

**How could I have fixed my USB key on Windows?**

### How'd I bork the USB key?

I was using `diskpart.exe` to reformat a USB key, and I realized I typed `format ft=fat32` instead of `format ft=fat32 quick`. So, of course, I pressed `Ctrl-C` to exit.

```
> list disk
[...]
> select disk 2
[...]
> clean
[...]
> create partition primary
[...]
> select partition 1
[...]
> active
[...]
> format fs=fat32
[ OOPS! Ctrl-C ]
```

Upon restarting `diskpart`, trying to reformat the partition gave errors:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 2    Online         7633 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> format fs=fat32 quick

Virtual Disk Service error:
A concurrent second call is made on an object before the first is completed.


DISKPART> format fs=fat32

Virtual Disk Service error:
A concurrent second call is made on an object before the first is completed.
```

So I tried running `clean`, which hung diskpart for a few seconds so I pressed Ctrl-C. Which was a mistake. The next runs of `diskpart` failed to show the device at all:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
```

I tried moving ports and opening `diskmgmt.msc`. Nothing!

I *did* get notifications that my USB device was not recognized, but with no actionable steps:

[image: USB device not recognized dialog]

### How'd I fix my USB key?

I went to my Mac, plugged in the device, and ~immediately got a prompt that Mac could not recognize the drive; it included buttons to `Initialize` the drive, which took me to Disk Utility.

In Disk Utility, I was easily able to erase the drive and reformat it with FAT.

### Question

Could I have done the same fix on my Windows device? All my searches found clickbaity results like "open Device Manager" or "uninstall drivers."

Thanks!

Comment: After the Mac formatted it, did you then confirm it was successful, by eject & reinsert, &/or test in the PC?

Comment: You can try removing all partitions and formatting FAT32 with a third-party tool, such as DiskGenius for Windows, https://www.diskgenius.com/ , but if that doesn't work, then likely the USB flash drive is toast. Flash memory has a finite lifetime. And, as mentioned, *properly eject* drive before physically removing it.

Comment: For clarity, the drive worked on my Mac after formatting and worked on my Windows, too, after I rebooted that machine.

Comment: There really is no way to do this on a Windows machine without a 3rd party tool?